# Trouble making my parser scroll downward

Tags: vba, excel, scroll, web-scraping, internet-explorer-11

I've written a script in vba to parse some information from a webpage. The thing is before scraping any information from that webpage I need to make my scraper scroll downward for few times. Here is where I'm stuck. The portion I need to make scroll is the left sided window. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[Website Link](http://catalogo.marmomac.it/it/cat)

Here is my try:

```
Sub Make_Scroll()
    Dim HTML As HTMLDocument, post As Object
    Dim Scroll As Object, URL$

    URL = "replace_with_above_link"

    With CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        .Visible = True
        .navigate URL
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set HTML = .document

        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:003")

        Set Scroll = HTML.querySelector(".iScrollLoneScrollbar[style*='z-index: 9999;']")
        Scroll.scrollTop = Scroll.scrollHeight
    End With
End Sub
```

The content for making scroll may be available within the below portion:

```
<div class="iScrollVerticalScrollbar iScrollLoneScrollbar" style="position: absolute; z-index: 9999; width: 7px; bottom: 2px; top: 2px; right: 1px; overflow: hidden;"><div class="iScrollIndicator" style="box-sizing: border-box; position: absolute; background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9); border-radius: 3px; width: 100%; transition-duration: 0ms; display: block; height: 8px; transform: translate(0px, 26px) translateZ(0px); transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.1, 0.57, 0.1, 1);"></div></div>
```

Comment: That page does not have a *standard* (HTML) scroll bar.

Comment: Whatever it is, there should be any way to do the trick using vba.

Comment: Try XHR instead of IE.

Comment: I'm not interested in their data at all. I just wish to know how to handle this type of situation using IE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the below example:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    ' Add references
    ' Microsoft XML, v6.0
    ' Microsoft HTML Object Library

    Dim sResponse As String
    Dim aResult() As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim oElement As HTMLDivElement

    With New XMLHTTP
        .Open "POST", "http://catalogo.marmomac.it/ajax/getListEspositori.php", False
        .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
        .Send "start=0&count=5000"
        sResponse = .ResponseText
    End With
    With New HTMLDocument
        .body.innerHTML = sResponse
        i = 1
        For Each oElement In .getElementsByClassName("elemento")
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1) = oElement.innerText
            i = i + 1
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

The output for me as follows, there are 1669 items total:

[image: output]

Comment: I was not expecting any solution other than scrolling that site using IE but you have already mesmerized me with your finest approach. This is damn good i meant, the way you have written the script. Thanks.