# Unable to make a split screen scroll to the bottom

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've written a script in python in combination with selenium to make the screen of a webpage scroll downward. The content is within the left-sided window. If I scroll down, more items are visible. I've tried with the below approach but It doesn't seem to work. Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Check out this: [website link](http://catalogo.marmomac.it/it/cat).

What I've tried so far with:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("find_the_link_above")

elem = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#pannello-espositori .luogo")))

for item in range(3):
    elem.send_keys(Keys.END)
    time.sleep(3)

driver.quit()
```

When I execute the above script, it throws an exception `can't focus element`.

Comment: to scroll the list: `window.iScrollElenco.scrollBy(0, -10000)`

Comment: Thanks Florent B. , for your suggestion. The thing is I can't find any idea where should I put `window.iScrollElenco.scrollBy(0, -10000)` this portion withing my script to make a go.

Comment: Why exactly do you want to scroll down? What is your validation point?

Comment: What do you mean by why, @DebanjanB? I really didn't understand your question. However, do you think it is impossible to achieve?

Comment: @Topto, `driver.execute_script("window.iScrollElenco.scrollBy(0, -10000)")`. but you'll have to wait for the dynamic content to be updated. It would be much more easier and efficient to send the  request directly to scrap the the data.

Comment: @Topto Each _usecase_ must be accompanied with a validation point. The solution is build up with respect to the validation point. Having said the point is **not being impossible** but **what you want to achieve**.

Comment: @DebanjanB, he/she is scraping the data, not validating a use-case.

Comment: @FlorentB. That makes sense but I don't see OP's code to collect/scrape data then the solution would have been much easier.

Comment: I'm not interested in their data @Florent B. I only wanted to scroll this split screen as it seemed to be difficult when I came it across in the first place. However, your suggested portion did the trick errorlessly. Thanks a lot for that. I am having hard time finding out the portion (you have suggested) in the page source.

Comment: @Topto, if you are not interested in their data, why did you add the `web-scraping` tag? Not to mention that you are talking about scraping the data in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49698554/trouble-making-my-parser-scroll-downward)

Comment: You are again getting me wrong @Florent B. I never showed interest in their data at all. I just accepted the answer in that post because I happened to notice this bit of code `"#elenco .elemento:last-child"` what you took out within moments. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: @Topto, try my answer, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. You can see scrolling effect by scrolling up to the elements in the left panel.

This solution would scroll up to first 100 elements.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

def scroll_element_into_view(element):
    driver.execute_script(
        "arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);",
        element)
    time.sleep(0.2) #increase/decrease time as you want delay in your view

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(5)
try:
    driver.get("http://catalogo.marmomac.it/it/cat")
    time.sleep(3)
    total_elems= driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".scroller .elemento")
    print len(total_elems)
    for i in range(len(total_elems)):
        scroll_element_into_view(total_elems[i])
except Exception as e:
    print e
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

As you have mentioned, after scroll it would load more elements.Below script would handle that too. Here we can use total count which already shown at top of the panel.

for ex count is : 1669

1. First it will scroll from 1 to 100 element
2. Again find total elements which is now 150
3. So it will scroll from 101 to 150
4. Again find total elements which is now 200
5. So it will scroll from 150 to 200

this process would continue till 1669 element. (Store previous count in one variable and update it after every loop)

```
try:
    driver.get("http://catalogo.marmomac.it/it/cat")
    time.sleep(3)
    total_elems=0
    total_count = int(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".totali").text)
    while total_elems<total_count:
        elems= driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".scroller .elemento")
        found_elms= len(elems)
        for i in range(total_elems,found_elms):
            scroll_element_into_view(elems[i])
        total_elems=found_elms
except Exception as e:
    print e
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use the following method for that:

```
def scroll_down():
    """A method for scrolling down the page."""

    # Get scroll height.
    last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('#pannello-espositori').scrollHeight;")

    while True:

        # Scroll down to the bottom.
        driver.execute_script("window.iScrollElenco.scrollBy(0, -arguments[0]);", last_height)

        # Wait to load the page.
        time.sleep(2)

        # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height.
        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.querySelector('#pannello-espositori').scrollHeight;")

        if new_height == last_height:

            break

        last_height = new_height
```

Use this method when you want to scroll down content (using the height of the left side panel) in the left side panel.

Hope it helps you! Let me know about the result.

Comment: Although I have't tried your answer yet, it seems the script will work. However, the reason I opened this bounty is only because I could not understand why I should go for `iScrollElenco` portion connected with `dots` around like `window.iScrollElenco.scrollBy()` and where should I find it. Cause If I didn't know what to use `window.<>.scrollBy()` in between, how can I track `iScrollElenco`? This little explanation suffices. Thanks.

Comment: If you call in the console of browser `window.iScrollElenco`, you can see that `IScroll` object is used (from script http://catalogo.marmomac.it/plugins/iscroll-master/build/iscroll.js).

Comment: @Topto, so, how is going?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like: 
**Option 1**

```
execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();",element)
```

**Option 2**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

element = driver.find_element_by_id("my-id")

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
```

Comment: Perhaps you are not familiar with `elem.send_keys(Keys.END)` method. It does the trick. However, I'm not getting it worked here. I'll give your suggestion a try.

Comment: Just added a possible extra solution. @Topto

Answer (score 1):

The selector `"#pannello-espositori .luogo"` gives part of the text in the first element in the panel. If you scroll down, this element is no longer visible and might not be able to get any more commands. You can locate the entire list and use `ActionChains` to scroll to the last element each time. It will be scrolled into view and will reload the list

```
actions = ActionChains(driver)
for item in range(3):
    elements = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#pannello-espositori .elemento")))
    actions.move_to_element(elements[-1]).perform()
```