# How to exit loop when scrollBy reaches the bottom of the web page?

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, web-scraping, lazy-loading

I've written a script in VBA using IE to reach the bottom of a web page automatically. The web page displays it's content in such a way that if I scroll downward more products become visible. I have used `.scrollBy` within my script to handle the lazy load.

I don't understand how to stop the scrolling when there is no more new products to load - I've used `.scrollBy` within a `Do` loop. How can I exit my loop when the scrolling is done and the browser reaches the bottom of the web page? Thanks in advance for any solution.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
Sub HandleLazyload()
    Const URL As String = "https://www.inc.com/profile/sumup-payments-limited"
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, HTML As HTMLDocument, post As Object

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate URL
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set HTML = .document
    End With

    Do
        HTML.parentWindow.scrollBy 0, 99999
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")
        Set post = HTML.getElementsByTagName("article")
    Loop         ''I wish to break out of this loop when all the scrolling is done
    IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Comment: A `Do loop` can be exited via either `Exit Do` (within an if-statement) or by changing the `Do` to a `Do While [condition]`.  If you are unsure of how to determine **when** you have reached the bottom of the page (or other condition to determine time to exit `Do`), it may be better to redefine your question (and /or title?) to better reflect the difficulty you're experiencing in determining the condition, rather than not knowing how to exit a 'Do loop'....  _(I personally don't know as much of accessing the web data with VBA, and editing title appropriately may help get required aid.)_

Comment: Thanks for your elaborative comment. The `do loop` within my script is just a placeholder to make the process go on. I would be very glad if i could get a suggestion as to what the title of this post will better fit @Mistella. Thanks.

Comment: @Topto Hello Topto - I've updated your question to hopefully be more clear to others. Generally the term is "exiting" a loop, not "getting rid of" one.

Comment: So I was trying to look into types of terms, and came across this Q&A:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/17967898/9259306  I know the question is for Javascript; however, the answer I linked to (by Miki Berkovich) seemed general enough you may find it helpful.

Comment: Your loop needs an `until` or `while` - and are you saying you'd like to add one to exit the loop when the scroll bar position is at the bottom of the page?

Comment: Without more information about what you're trying to do and where you're stuck it's hard to give a straight answer, but perhaps [this alternative approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49701184/8112776) will be applicable.

Comment: There is no room for confusion as to what I'm trying to do. However, If i come again: I wish to reach the bottom of that webpage using IE. When the browser reach the bottom then quits gracefully. That's it and nothing else.

Comment: @ashleedawg Did you realize that the `alternative approach` you pointed to was Q&A for a question asked by the **same user**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following where I used the rank to determine termination/exit of loop.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub HandleLazyload()
    Const URL As String = "https://www.inc.com/profile/sumup-payments-limited"
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, HTML As HTMLDocument
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate URL
        While .Busy = True Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        Set HTML = .document
    End With

    Dim rank As Long, item As Long
    item = 1

    Do While Err.Number = 0
        HTML.parentWindow.scrollBy 0, 99999
        Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)
        On Error GoTo errhand
        rank = Split(HTML.querySelectorAll(".rank dt ~ dd")(item).innerText, "#")(1)
        item = item + 1
    Loop

errhand:
    Err.Clear
    Debug.Print "Stopped at rank " & rank

    'Your other code
    'IE.Quit
End Sub
```

Notes:

**CSS Selector:**

In case you want to know more about the CSS selector

The selector below targets all elements where class name is `rank` and then has sibling elements `dt` and `dd` within.

```
HTML.querySelectorAll(".rank dt ~ dd")(item)
```

**Targeted HTML:**

[image: HTML element]

Comment: Thanks QHarr, for your solution. The logic you applied above works in this site as the site updates it's content with a single item upon each scroll. The same logic will fail if you try on this `https://www.yellowpages.ca/search/si/1/coffee/all%20states`. However, it's a good idea to go with. Gonna accept your solution. Thanks again.

Comment: Cool. When I have some spare time I will have a look at what I can do with that other link.